# Composited render missing occlusion with white outline

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, render-layers

I am trying to learn how to render out elements in different layers. For some reason I am getting a couple issues when I attempt to composite 2 layers.

Below is a combined render of all elements, and a composited version of the creature, smoke, and background. The composited version has a weird outline around the creature, and there is no shadows/ambient occlusion on it as well.

I have a view layer setup for the creature and the smoke elements. The explosion in the creature view layer is set to "indirect only" and the creature in the smoke view layer is set to "holdout"

google drive link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wbUuCqGi34zJxhbVCxcOr2-yuIAoZNGn/view?usp=drive_link

edit: The white outline issue was solved by setting the premultiplied values on the alpha over nodes to 1.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If no one answers your question, you can try compositing the finished render in Gimp to remove the white outline and paint shadows for each frame.

Comment: i would recommend providing a blend file - i think this attracts way more people

Comment: From the screenshots, the monster and smoke are on different layers, and each layer has a transparent background. Maybe this video is helpful, though I am not sure: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmb5HRU1cUo

Comment: The link to the file requires an account.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67346/where-do-the-white-lines-come-from-in-my-composite

Comment: your google drive link is not accessible. can you please make it public.

Comment: I just did, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking "Convert Premultiplied" for one or both of the "Alpha Over" nodes.
It looks like the alpha channel of the creature is not premultiplied and it might help.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work